# there is an unexpected result for the if statement in android studio, why?

Tags: java, android, if-statement, expandablelistview

in my expandable list view I wrote the (if) statement that returns a (dialog) if two words are contained in the child Row ..

and here is the code:

```
.......
    childObjects.add(new ChildObject(cetamol + " " + syr + " 160 " + mg5ml
                , cetamolDoseMini160));
    ..........



    elv = findViewById(R.id.elv);
    elv.setOnGroupExpandListener(onGroupExpandListenser);

    MyExpandableAdapter adapter = new MyExpandableAdapter(this, getData());
    elv.setAdapter(adapter);

    elv.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {

            for (int i = 0; i < ((ViewGroup) v).getChildCount(); ++i) {
                View nextChild = ((ViewGroup) v).getChildAt(i);
                if (nextChild.getId() == R.id.txtChildName) {
                    String data = ((TextView) nextChild).getText().toString();

                    String paracetamol = getResources().getString(R.string.Paracetamol);

                
                    if (data.contains(paracetamol)|| data.contains("160")) {

                        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Analgesics.this);

                        builder.setTitle(" Paracetamol 160:");

                        String[] drugsTrades = {"Hayamol 160 ", "Paradrin 160 "};

                        builder.setItems(drugsTrades, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            }
                        });
                        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                        // dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.color.translucent_black);
                        dialog.show();
                    }

                }
            }
                return true;
            }
    });
```

but the (if statement) saw (just) the first part "paracetamol" and didn't see the second part "160"

Comment: Are you sure the problem isn't with the first `if` statement, where you seem to be comparing strings with `==` instead of `.equals()`?

Comment: I used (data.contains) instead of (data.equals) , I want to return a value when the two word are present in the raw

Comment: I'm talking about the _first_ `if`, not the second.  Where you use `==`.  Don't do that.

Comment: To the _second_ `if`, try using `&&` instead of `||` because if the left side is true, then the right side is not evaluated. ([short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation))

Comment: the `==` worked well in the first `if` , I  tested it with `Toast` and it returned the true result.

Comment: Yeah, really don't use `==` to compare strings.  Even if it occasionally works.  But just to understand ... are you saying you were trying to match strings that contained "paracetamol" AND "160", rather than one or the other?  If that's the case, yes, use `&&` instead of `||` for AND.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem I'd like to thank you very much ,
I used `&&` instead of `||` ,and the problem was solved.

Comment: @PaulT. thank you very much , my problem was solved using your suggesion.

Answer (score -1):

Replace your whole code by this code.

```
.......
childObjects.add(new ChildObject(cetamol + " " + syr + " 160 " + mg5ml
            , cetamolDoseMini160));
..........



elv = findViewById(R.id.elv);
elv.setOnGroupExpandListener(onGroupExpandListenser);

MyExpandableAdapter adapter = new MyExpandableAdapter(this, getData());
elv.setAdapter(adapter);

elv.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {

        for (int i = 0; i < ((ViewGroup) v).getChildCount(); ++i) {
            View nextChild = ((ViewGroup) v).getChildAt(i);
            if (nextChild.getId() == R.id.txtChildName) {
                String data = ((TextView) nextChild).getText().toString();

                String paracetamol = getResources().getString(R.string.Paracetamol);

            
                if (data.contains(paracetamol) && data.contains("160")) {

                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Analgesics.this);

                    builder.setTitle(" Paracetamol 160:");

                    String[] drugsTrades = {"Hayamol 160 ", "Paradrin 160 "};

                    builder.setItems(drugsTrades, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        }
                    });
                    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                    // dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.color.translucent_black);
                    dialog.show();
                }

            }
        }
            return true;
        }
});
```